# Derived Group Scheme

Tags: ct.category-theory, group-schemes

If $G$ is a $k-$ group scheme (seeing as a functor) exist a good definition of what is the derived group scheme? (Or a good reference for a good definition). Where derived I'm talking in the sense of group theory.

PS:We may assume that $G$ is of finite type and smooth.

Comment: Just to be extra clear, by *derived group* you mean the commutator subgroup?

Comment: Yes, the group generated by the commutators in the group theory setting. I have read that if $G'$ is the derived group scheme and $R$ is a $k-$ algebra then $G'(R)\subset G(R)'$ (with $G(R)'$ the derived group in group theory setting) and we have the equality if $R$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.

Comment: What does "well-behaved" mean?  That $G$ is of finite type over $k$ (but just not necessarily smooth)?  Is there some specific purpose motivating the question, or idle curiosity?

Comment: @JoãoDias I do not remember the details, but why can't you just take the scheme-theoretic image of the commutator morphism $G\times G\to G$ and endow it with a group structure? This should work at least when $k$ is of characteristic 0.

Comment: I was wondering If that would work, but I can't find any reference on this subject.

Comment: Some standard references that you should consult are Demazure and Gabriel's "Groupes Algebriques," Jantzen's "Representations of Algebraic Groups," or Waterhouse's "Introduction to Affine Group Schemes."

Comment: The representabiliy of the derived group functor is given in sections 2.3 and 2.4 of Borel's "Linear Algebraic Groups".

Comment: @DenisNardin the scheme-theoretic image of the commutator morphism is not always a group (you have to take the group it generates). It isn't even a group in the case of finite groups.

Comment: @PeterMcNamara Oops you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following quote, from Pseudo-reductive groups by Conrad, Gabber and Prasad (Definition A.1.14, lightly edited) should answer your question.

> The derived group D(G) of a smooth group G of finite type
>   over a field k is the unique smooth closed k-subgroup such that (D(G))(K) is
>   the commutator subgroup of G(K) for any algebraically closed extension K/k.
>
> Note that the derived group exists without connectedness hypotheses on
>   G; see [Bo2, I, 2.4] for the affine case and [SGA3,
>   VI B , 7.2(vii), 7.10] for the general case. The formation of D(G) commutes
>   with any extension of the base field, and the quotient map G → G/D(G) is
>   initial among all k-homomorphisms from G to a commutative k-group scheme
>   (see Lemma 5.3.4 for a generalization).

[Bo2] is the same reference to Borel's "Linear Algebraic Groups" that was provided in a comment by Uri Bader.

Comment: One can also see Demazure-Gabriel's Groupes Algebriques Tome I, chapter II, 5.4.8 (though my French is a bit too weak to be sure what their precise assumptions are).